# Post incrementing operator and array assignment

Tags: java, arrays, class

Here is the code below:

```
public class Country{

    private String name;
    private City [] cities;
    private int index =0;

    public Country (String n, int nrc){  // nrc as in number of cities
        name = n;
        cities = new City[nrc];
    }
    public boolean exists (City str){
        for(int i =0; i>index;i++){
            if(cities[i].equals(str)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void addCity (City str){
        if(str == null){
            System.out.print("City not initialized!");
        }
        if(exists(str)){
            System.out.print("City  exists!");
        }
        if(cities.length == index){
            System.out.print("Not enough space in array!");
        }
        cities[index++] = str;
    }
}
```

I want to know what `cities[index++] = str` is supposed to do. Can anyone help?

Comment: for example `cities[1] = "Dublin"`

Comment: What do you think it is supposed to do? we can just copy paste some lines from a textbook, but it would be more helpful for you, if we can help you on your way yourself

Comment: @B001ᛦ No! ``index`` is incremented afterwards, that is the important part!

Comment: @B001ᛦ ... that makes no sense, even as a comment. He has no Strings in his statement, he just used the quotation marks to show the start and end of the statement, your (half-)line of code wouldn't even compile

Comment: @Stultuske ok, flag as bad comment and move on---- and also read OP's comment below _I know what index++ does just not what the whole cities[index] = str is doing_

Comment: @Stultuske i can send the other class thats connected to this exercise but youre already mad so thanks all!

Comment: @zirael I'm not mad. I'm just pointing out that for you to learn and understand, it's better for you to first try and figure it out, and then to verify what you think is correct or not. that way, you'll have looked up information, and might have gathered additional information, but at least will have read about the keywords ... we'll use when explaining, so it will make our explanations a whole lot easier for you to follow and understand

Comment: @Stultuskeas i said i appreciate the help from all thanks everyone!

Comment: @zirael : Accept and upvote an answer if you have got your clarification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say you have

```
String [] cities = {"Paris","Cairo", "Addis Ababa"}
```

range index will be  `0 upto cities.length-1`
use this index values to get element from array or  to add/set element into the array so 
to get element `"cairo"`, we use

```
String str = cities[1]; // we got element "cairo"
```

to set element `"Paris"`

```
cities[0] = "London";
```

so in your case:

```
cities[index++] = str;
```

is adding element str into array `cities` at `index=index`

Answer (score 3):

It adds the City to the current index position in the cities arrays and increments the index position.

Comment: It's not the next position. It's the current position

Answer (score 2):

Not clear which part is confusing you, but it's equivalent to this

```
cities[index] = str;
index = index + 1;
```

Which stores the string into the array `cities` at position `index` and moves the position `index` forward for the next insert

Comment: I know what index++ does just not what the whole cities[index] = str is doing

Comment: @zirael it assigns the value of str to the element with index 'index' of the array cities

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call the method addCity(), the variable index will increment by one each time. Since cities is an array, it allows us to add variables into the element spaces in the array without specifying the specific position each time.

So for example, if you want to add the city Toronto for example, it would go into cities[0], then the next time you want to add another city, the next city would go into cities[1] automatically, and so on.